# semantic-based version control tool for merging code

Tags: git, version-control

When I merge from other developer, I may meet different coding style code. The differences are from indent or whitespace. Are there semantic-based version control tool (or plugin for git/svn/... ) ?

Comment: This isn't a solution, but it's a very good idea to define the style for a project so that everybody's code looks the same. Code following a style guide is easier to merge, but also just easier to read.

Comment: Thx a lot :) But actually I am interested in whether good tools to do semantic code merge  :)

Comment: Look at [Git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). You can try to combine it with some tool for automatic code formatting.